# Find variable using a string

Tags: vb.net

There is this specific thing I'm trying to do, not sure how to call it, it basically goes like this.

Finding a variable using string or something similar:

Two Buttons, with name Car and Bus.

```
Dim New_Car as String
Dim New_Bus as String

'Then when either buttons is pressed
New_<button_name_here> = Something
```

It worked when I did something similar with

```
My.Settings(<button_name_here>) = Something
```

But in this case it's showing syntax error and I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to Settings by using a Dictionary

```
    Dim buttonValue As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"Car", ""}, {"Bus", ""}}

    buttonValue("Car") = "Some value"
```

An other option would be to initialize your key at startup by looping all your buttons.

```
Loop all button
    buttonValue.Add(<Button name>, <initial value>)
```

Comment: Yes there are other ways to accomplish what I want, but I want this specific one liner kind of way which changes the Variable.

Comment: @CruleD the one liner is to use the Dictionary

Comment: but the dictionary won't change my variable as given in the example.

Comment: There's no way to do a oneliner with a variable, especially one that is local (based on the use of Dim).

Comment: and if it's in class eg form1 and used across methods? Also what if I would search for it with full name instead of partially combining them, like (<variable_name?_from_string>)=something

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single handler for both buttons. Determine which button is clicked with the sender

```
Private Sub Vehicle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bus.Click, Car.Click
    Dim buttonName = DirectCast(sender, Button).Name
    Select Case buttonName
        Case "Car"
            Dim New_Car = "something"
        Case "Bus"
            Dim New_Bus = "something else"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I know, I don't actually need buttons, that was just an example. I'm interested in doing it the way I described in OP. Ifs, dictionaries...etc are things that would normally be done. Wanted to do it that way since it looks cleaner, instead of like 50 lines long case select.